# Ultra weakly closed *-subalgebra of B(H)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I'm currently working on a text about von Neumann algebras and the author used without further clarifying that any ultra weakly closed *-subalgebra of $B(H)$ contains a largest projection. Could someone tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
V := AH^{\perp} = \{x \in H : x\perp ay \quad\forall a\in A, y\in H\}
$$
Let $W$ be the orthogonal complement of $V$, then $W$ is a non-degenerate representation of $A$. It is a consequence of the [Double Commutant theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_bicommutant_theorem) that
$$
\text{id}_W : W\to W
$$
is an ultra-strong limit of elements of $A$. Hence, $A$ contains $\text{id}_W$, which can be identified with the orthogonal projection $e\in B(H)$ onto $W$. Furthermore,
$$
A = Ae
$$
So for any other projection $f\in A = Ae$, we must have
$$
f = fe
$$
and so $f\leq e$. Hence, $e$ is the largest projection in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Say $M\subset B(H)$ is your von Neumann algebra. Let $\mathcal P=\{p\in M:\ p \text{ is a projection }\}$.  Let $K\subset H$ be the subspace generated by $\bigcup_{p\in\mathcal P}pH$, and write $p_K$ for the orthogonal projection onto $K$.

Then for any $q\in \mathcal P$, $p_Kq=q$. This implies that $q\leq p_K$, and also that $p_kq=qp_K$. For any projection $r\in M'$, 
$$
rpH=prH\subset pH,
$$
so $rK\subset K$. This implies that $p_Krp_K=rp_K$, from where it follows that $rp_K=p_Kr$. So $p_K\in M''=M$.

The above is a sketch of the proof that in a von Neumann algebra arbitrary unions of projections are again in the algebra.

Comment: Thank you. What I don't understand is this: If M is a von Neumann algebra, it contains the identity on H, so K=H, right? I need to show that $p_K$ is in $M$, if M is an ultra weakly closed *-subalgebra

Comment: Yes, if it is non-degenerate. In that case, the largest projection you are looking for is the identity. In general, it will be the identity of $M$, which may or may not agree with the identity of $B(H)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still a little confused. By definition, a von Neumann Algebra $M\subseteq B(H)$ contains the identity. If $M$ is merely a ultraweakly closed *-subalgebra, then it is $M\subseteq M''$ and not necessarily $p_K \in M$? From what I understand I need to look at $N:=\{ T_{|K} | T \in M\}$ and show that it is an algebra containing 1.

Comment: I see your point now. If you look at the first part of my answer, it shows that $M=p_KMp_K$, so you can consider $M\subset B(K)$ where it is a von Neumann algebra. Then it contains $I_{B(K)=p_K$.